# Choosing different compression algorithm depending on output mime type in .net5/6

Tags: asp.net, .net-core, compression

Modern .net backends will pick Brotli if supported by the browser. My problem is that like 50% of the outgoing traffic from one of our backends is binary data. So what I would like to do is to intercept the request handling and make sure that gzip is used when binary data is going to be sent out. Is that possible somehow?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a config like:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.ResponseCompression;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Services.AddResponseCompression(options =>
{
    options.Providers.Add<BrotliCompressionProvider>();
    options.Providers.Add<GzipCompressionProvider>();
    options.MimeTypes = ResponseCompressionDefaults.MimeTypes.Concat(
        new[] { "application/octet-stream" });
});
var app = builder.Build();
app.UseResponseCompression();
```

Your *client* can choose which compression to request via setting the `Accept-Encoding`

```
Accept-Encoding: gzip
```

You can also have `Accept-Encoding: *` and server can use a default or custom provider for a specific mime type. Have a look at examples [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/response-compression?view=aspnetcore-6.0).

Comment: We don't have immediate control over the clients. Most of them sends "Accept-encoding:  br, gzip, deflate" and in that case the .net backend will choose "br" no matter what mime type the output data has. This is too bad since gzip gives me better compression on our binary data compared to brotli. But according to you the solutions lays in the client implementation, I can not change the priority of which compression that is picked by the backend, it will always pick brotli if that is supported by the client?

Comment: Not sure, I will suggest some options to try: 1. Increase compression level for Brotli so it compresses better (but slower, as higher compression means more CPU), e.g. `CompressionLevel.Optimial` 2. Remove support for `"application/octet-stream"` for brotli compressor and add it to gzip. You do it via passing what MIME types are supported. Example for compression level and mime type: https://gunnarpeipman.com/aspnet-core-compress-gzip-brotli-content-encoding/. 3. Implement a custom compressor with a custom mime type. I hope 1 or 2 will solve the issue. What's the binary content?

Comment: thanks for your reply. Well the data is rather obscure, its a bunch of different measurements being made by various kinds of industrial machines. It is your option number two that I'm after but it seems impossible. I will look into option number 3. Thanks!)